# Python untitest: need to use setUpClass() and tearDownClass() with version 2.6.3

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.6

I got to know from other posts and also verified from Python docs that setUpClass() and tearDownClass() can be used in Python 2.7 and 3.2 or above, but due to some existing dependency I have to use Python 2.6.3.

As of now I have written Selenium Webdriver test scripts in Python and using unittest framework from 2.6.3 to run these tests. I have put common code like launching application and login in setUp() and quitting driver instance in tearDown() methods. But it is causing to launch app during every test_ method in Test Class.

As 2.6.3 does not support setUpClass() and tearDownClass(), I am looking for alternative so my tests in single test class will not repeat the setup for each test run.